# Setspace: command \singlespacing already defined

Tags: packages

I would like to use the command `\setstrech` from the `setspace` package, but loading the package seems to clash with the document class `imsart` that I am using. Both seem to be defining `\singlespacing` and perhaps other common commands. Is there a simple way around this, say by telling Latex to override the package definitions with those of the documnetclass?

Example code that need to function without `setspace` package, the `imsart` 
can be found [here](http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html):

```
\documentclass[aos,preprint]{imsart}
% link to imsart:
% http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand{\IIf}[1]{\State\algorithmicif\ #1 \algorithmicthen}

% \usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \setcounter{algorithm}{2}
    \caption{Simple Algorithm}
    % \setstretch{1.25}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \State \makebox[2.00in][l]{Initialize $x$} $x^{(5)} \gets \mathcal L( u^{(2)}, A^{(3,4)})$
        \State \makebox[2.00in][l]{Update $y$} $y^{(5)} \gets \mathcal L( x^{(5)}, A^{(6,7)})$

    \end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load `setspace`. The `imsart` class is for submissions to some journal, so you shouldn't monkey with the spacing *they* want.

Comment: You should definitely follow egreg's advice. :-) However, if you *must* monkey around, try issuing the instruction `\RequirePackage{setspace}` immediately *before* the `\documentclass` instruction. No guarantees this won't break something else though.

Comment: @egreg, thanks, I just need to change the spacing between lines in the `algorithm` environment which I think they would be fine with. I remember a long time ago I settled on `\setstrech{1.2}` as a solution. Is there a simple way of doing it within the `algorithm` without loading the package.

Comment: @passerby51 Please, add a small example of code to play with.

Comment: @egreg, sample code added.

Comment: I can't see `imsart` (also add a pointer to it on the net).

Comment: @egreg, I have added it including the pointer.

Comment: You can use \doublespacing or \singlespacing options. Check imsart.sty and you can update the value for double spacing too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply change the `\linespread` value within the `algorithm`. (I've used a larger value to show the effect).

```
\documentclass[aos,preprint]{imsart}
% link to imsart:
% http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcommand{\algorithmicoutput}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand{\IIf}[1]{\State\algorithmicif\ #1 \algorithmicthen}




\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \setcounter{algorithm}{2}
    \caption{Simple Algorithm}
    \linespread{2.25}\selectfont
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \State \makebox[2.00in][l]{Initialize $x$} $x^{(5)} \gets \mathcal L( u^{(2)}, A^{(3,4)})$
        \State \makebox[2.00in][l]{Update $y$} $y^{(5)} \gets \mathcal L( x^{(5)}, A^{(6,7)})$

    \end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\linespread{1.25}\selectfont` is simpler.

Comment: You're right. I'll update the answer.